# XML parse with PHP - SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a XML which I parse with PHP SimpleXML. Some parts of my XML file are like this:

```
<deviceStatusPolling interval="60">
    <r:datapoint programmaticName="t_val_sys_pct_mssDbPartitionUsage" /> 
</deviceStatusPolling>
```

When I parse it that is what I get:

```
Parsing 'deviceStatusPolling'...
    Has 1 attribute(s):
    - interval: 60
```

It does not parse the children:

```
    <r: datapoint programmaticName="t_val_sys_pct_mssDbPartitionUsage" />
```

This is the parse function:

```
function parse_recursive(SimpleXMLElement $element, $level = 0) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $level); // determine how much we'll indent

$value = trim((string) $element);  // get the value and trim any whitespace from the start and end
$attributes = $element->attributes();   // get all attributes
$children = $element->children();     // get all children

echo "{$indent}Parsing '{$element->getName()}'...<br>";
if(count($children) == 0 && !empty($value)) // only show value if there is any and if there aren't any children
{
    echo "{$indent}Value: {$element}<br>";
}

// only show attributes if there are any
if(count($attributes) > 0)
{
    echo $indent.'Has '.count($attributes).' attribute(s):<br>';
    foreach($attributes as $attribute)
    {
        echo "{$indent}- {$attribute->getName()}: {$attribute}<br>";
    }
}

// only show children if there are any
if(count($children))
{
    echo $indent.'Has '.count($children).' child(ren):<br>';
    foreach($children as $child)
    {
        parse_recursive($child, $level+1); // recursion :)
    }
}

echo $indent; // just to make it "cleaner"
echo "<br>";
}
```

Is it a limitation of SimpleXML? Or am I doing something wrong?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO! Show us your code/what your doing to print it.

Comment: also, please tell us what do you expect from its printing.

Comment: Its not obvious what you print and what you want to achieve.

Comment: what I want to achieve is to print the atribute interval-60 and the node r:datapoint

Comment: We still can't see what you're doing to print it - what code? Print?

Comment: r:datapoint is children of deviceStatusPolling but it does not get printed. Other elements in the same xml file that has children have the children printed but those children does not have the "r:"

Comment: and it should not. it is a separate node. if you like to print all nodes inside the outermost you need to traverse all children and treat them in order

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but probably need something like this:

```
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($docStr);
$allNamespaces = $xmlDoc->getNamespaces(true);
foreach ($allNamespaces as $nspace => $nurl) {
      $xmlDoc->registerXPathNamespace($nspace, $nurl);
}
```

Read up on SimpleXML and Namespaces.

This is almost certainly the fix to your problem. See here:
http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302